# Process all messages in websocket with no lost message in python

Tags: python, websocket

I've a websocket connexion that receives a lot of messages per seconds, and it requires couple of seconds to consume one message, so I believe I am losing a lot of messages.

```
async with connect(wss) as ws:
    await ws.send({"method": "subscribe"})
    subscription_response = await ws.recv()

    while True:
       message = await wait_for(ws.recv(), timeout=15)
       response = json.loads(message)
       consume(response)
```

How could I do to properly consume each message please?